# Detect if there is any hash value in the clicked url

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fragment-identifier

Is there is any way to detect the clicked link having hash?

### such as

```
<a href="www.mysite.com/muaz#hesam">Home</a>
```

Is there any way to detect `#hesam` / `existance of hash` and then get the hash value? I have three different kinds of url some has only `#` some have value : `#value` and some have plain url `www.coco.com` etc i want to detect each of them and then do the default task

### I want to use like this

```
if(plain Url){
  //do some thing
} else if (have only hash){
  // do other things
} else if (have hash with value){
  //do others
}
```

Comment: Any reason as to why you aren't using querystrings?

Answer (score 4):

Well, we have a property just for this on `location` object.

```
console.log(location.hash);
```

It will be with `#` however, but you can remove it and use the rest.

```
console.log(location.hash.substr(1))
```

You could do it like this if you want to

```
$('a').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault(); // prevent default action
   var hash = this.href.split("#")[1] || "no hash";    
});
```

Note: You can use `String.indexOf` to check if the url has `#`. If it returns `-1` there is no hash. Else, it has.

Comment: I've provided all the methods. Just use them according to your use case